# GettingJSONDecodeError when i am using the googletrans in python

Tags: python-3.x, google-translation-api, googletrans

I am using googletrans for converting other language text to english but i ma getting the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
translation = translator.translate('東京海洋大学')
print (translation)
```